# Animation transfer from Motionbuilder to Maya

Tags: python, api, animation, maya, motionbuilder

I'm querying values from Motionbuilder human Ik controls and keying those values inside Maya HumanIK, the animation came in perfectly except for the wrist part. I checked the values, they are accurate but the animation is different. Does anyone know why this happens? Can't figure it out. I tried in Maya versions 2016, 2017, 2018 btw I'm using Motionbuilder 2016

Comment: Is it possible for you to include [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to the question?

Comment: Sorry can't add images yet. Plus I'm not allowed to share code